# How to have a doubly-linked list point to a string

Tags: c++, pointers, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to make the .h file for my first assignment after a long break, little rusty with code.  All i need to do is make a Node that has a m_next an m_prev and a pointer to a string, i am completely stuck on how you make the pointer to the string, i have always been bad with pointers.

```
    class DoublyLinkedList
{
public:
    DoublyLinkedList();
    ~DoublyLinkedList();
    bool empty();
    void append(string&);
    void insertBefore(string&);
    void insertAfter(string&);
    void remove(string&);
    void begin();
    void end();
    bool next();
    bool prev();
    bool find(string&);
    const &data getData()
private:
    Class Node
    {
    public:
        Node (string* data, Node *next, Node *prev)
        {m_data = data; m_next = next; m_prev = prev;}
        string m_data;
        Node * m_next;
        Node * m_prev;
    };
    Node *m_head;
    Node *m_tail;
    Node *m_current;
};
#endif // DOUBLYLINKEDLIST_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: Does using `string* m_data` cause errors?

Comment: Why do you want it to be a pointer?

Answer (score 0):

change string m_data to string* m_data in the Node class